# Position a div center eg height:auto;

Tags: html, css, center

I can't believe i am asking this but i have a page where inside a wrapper center div there are a div with 4 boxes and another div by the side of it with content. The boxes will never change size but the content box will. For consistency i want to have the div with the content in center half way down the page so whenever more content is added it is always in that location. For some reason i've tried height/margin:auto and many methods and it just wont seem to center.

I have linked here a simple example of the div layout and what each div is styled like, seriously please tell me this is something i have easily missed out- quite embarrassing really!

All code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SBFrq/3/

```
eg 
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail1</div>
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail2</div>
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail3</div>
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            Content
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need javascript

Comment: i didnt understand, where do you want to put your content div ? at the bottom of the page ? have u tried `position:absolut` and `bottom:10px` ?

Comment: No not at the bottom just the content div half way down to the div on the left and when more text is added the div extends but staying half way down the wrapper div. Sorry if my link with the example is not clear

Answer (score 0):

These inline style adjustments should do the trick (if i understand you well).

The height on .content-wrapper is a rough estimate so you do need to tweak it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail1</div>
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail2</div>
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail3</div>
        <div class="col-13">thumbnail4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper" style="height: 500px; display: table; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="content" style="top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <div style="position: relative; #top: -50%">
            ContentContentContent
            <br>ContentContentContent
            <br>ContentContentContent
            <br>ContentContentContent
            <br>ContentContent
            <br>ContentContentContent
            <br>ContentContent
            <br>ContentContentContent
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: let me have a play around with this code and i will let you know, thank you :)

Comment: Isn't this what you meant?